# globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-MY"

Tags: globalization

HI,
Im using **Windows XP sp2** as my development platform,
I'm having problem in displaying **currency symbol**. 
You see,for Malaysia the correct currency symbol is **RM**, 
but when I used *uiCulture="ms" culture="ms-MY"* the currency symbol displayed is **R**. After googling for this problem I've found out that there's a way to correct this problem, given I have to use *uiCulture="en" culture="en-MY"*. When I apply this to the web.config, compile error.
*The  tag contains an invalid value for the 'culture' attribute.*
And I googled again then I found out that this culture only supported in Vista.
Is there any workaround for this problem, beside installing Vista.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom culture for en-MY. You can use the culture from Vista as a template.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That link is no longer valid

Comment: Looks like v4.5 might not support anymore? Changed link to explicitly reference v4.